# 2d array that calculates and stores 6 random connected points

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, random

I am trying to make an 80x20 2D array that creates 6 lines that are randomly connected between two points on the perimeter of the array. I imagine it's going to look like a picture framed in only some places. My problem is, that I don't know how to select and link two random dots on the array's perimeter and display them. I made a code selecting completely random points, but can't seem to solve this assignment. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int rows = 80; //declares the amount of rows in the 2d array
    const int cols = 20; //declares the amount of columns in the 2d array
    char sky[rows][cols];

    fill_n(&sky[0][0], 100, '-'); 
    fill_n(&sky[0][0] + 100, rows*cols - 100, ' '); 
    random_shuffle(&sky[0][0], &sky[0][0] + rows*cols); 

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            cout << sky[r][c];
            cout << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the significance of the hyphens and spaces (`'-'` and `' '`) in `sky`? Also, did you mean to print all rows on the same line?

Comment: This code was originally used to make a 2d array that has stars placed randomly in it. All the other spaces were blanks.

Comment: I see, so the hyphens represent star. Are you trying to extend this code to include the decribed functionality or just posting it as an example of what you know how to do? Based on your description, it sounds like the entire line must be on the perimeter (not just the endpoints). Is this correct? If so, can a "line" traverse a corner or must it be entirely on one side?

Comment: Yes, the entire line should be on the perimeter. The line has to be straight, so I think it has to be on one side. I am trying to extend this code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Visualize your array as follows in a simplified example

```
[0][0], [0][1], [0][2], [0][3]
[1][0], [1][1], [1][2], [1][3]
[2][0], [2][1], [2][2], [2][3]
[3][0], [3][1], [3][2], [3][3]
```

You can see that your perimeter indices will be the first and last rows, and the first and last columns. I'll leave the implementation to you, but you should be able to use this subset of your 2D array to select the values you wish to connect.

Good luck on your assignment!

Comment: But how do I get the program to select and connect two points in the perimeter?

Comment: we haven't learned to do that yet. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @Trollslayer What have you not learned how to do yet? Traverse an array?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your description right, you want to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
for i in 1..6
{ pick one of four sides of the rectangle at random
  pick a random point p1 on that side

  pick one of the other three sides at random
  pick a random point p2 on that side

  use a line drawing algorithm (like Bresenham) to connect p1 and p2
}
```

Starting with an algorithm that fills an array and randomly shuffles it around is likely to be .... inefficient .... although, as the argument goes, eventually one of the random permutations will hit on what you want...